# add jquery in angualr2 component template

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I am trying to add **jquery onclick** event in component templat e.g. app.component.html

```
<li>
    <a id="menu-close" href="#services">Services</a>
</li>
```

and I wrote a function in a **custom.js** file e.g.

```
$("#menu-close").click(function(e) {
    ....
}
```

But I don't know how to load custom.js, is just add

```
<script src="js/custom.js"></script>
```

in index.html?

Comment: You don't need `jquery` when you use `angular`. try implementing angular options like `ng-click` in `html`. Also to load `custom.js` specify relative path for your `js` file

Answer (score 0):

you just try this...

```
// In the console
// First install jQuery
npm install --save jquery
// and jQuery Definition
npm install -D @types/jquery
```

import your jquery..

```
// CommonJS style - working with "require"
import $ = require('jquery')
//
//then add your jquery here...
$("#menu-close").click(function(e) {
    ....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
<a id="menu-close" href="#services" (click)='test()'>Services</a>
```

IN .ts file:

```
public test(): void{
    alert('success');
  }
```

If you want to put the test() function in common place, u can write the same code in service file and import to respective components.